# Implementing registerForActivityResult from Fragment to dismiss Activity class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

I have a calling like

There is a
-> FragmentMain which calls ActivityA
-> ActivityA consists of ActivityA_FragmentA
-> ActivityA_FragmentA  calls ActivityB
-> ActivityB consists of ActivityB_FragmentA  , ActivityB_FragmentB , ActivityB_FragmentC

ActivityB_FragmentC  is final fragment on whose Ok button , I need to dismiss and return to FragmentMain

Current Implementation:
-> On dismiss of ActivityB_FragmentC  updates LiveData to which is observed on ActivityB
-> This LiveData on ActivityB Used setResult(1000) in ActivityB and then finishActivity
-> Using onActivityResult()  in ActivityA  (result code used to compare 1000) {if result code is 1000 then dismiss ActivityA to show FragmentMain   }

How to implement this using . registerForActivityResult()
I checked the document for it [Doc Link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#separate)

It says to use Observer and has explanation only for camera fetch .

I needed a simple call where I can pass result code back .. How can I achieve this ?

I want to use registerForActivityResult() in place of onActivityResult() in ActivityA

Trial 1 :

> class MyLifecycleObserver(private val registry :
> ActivityResultRegistry)
> : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
> lateinit var getContent : ActivityResultLauncher
>
> ```
> override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
>     getContent = registry.register("key", owner, ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
>         // Handle the returned Uri
>     }
> }
>
> fun selectImage() {
>     getContent.launch("image/*")
> } }
> ```

Am trying to pass result/ call  from ActivityA_FragmentA  to ActivityA   but am able to do it using

> ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()

Comment: It is unclear where you use or wanna use registerForActivityResult(). (Please put that in your post).

Comment: @blackapps  Want to use registerForActivityResult() in ActivityA  in place of onActivityResult()

Comment: registerForActivityResult()  is a replacement for startActivityForResult(). Not for onActivityResult.

Comment: @blackapps Ok , so we need to call registerForActivityResult() in ActivityA_FragmentA .. So what happens to onActivityResult()

Comment: `FragmentMain which calls ActivityA` And how will you 'call' ActivityA if you wanna return to FragmentMain?

Comment: I wonder: Have you implemented all with startActivityForResult now? And the problem is to replace that deprecated stuff with the registerfor stuff?

Comment: @blackapps  Yes , I have implemented it and it works fine, FragmentMain calls ActivityA . ActivityA has onActivityResult() which checks resultCode and performs dismiss of ActivityA. 

ActivityA_FragmentA  calls ActivityB using startActivityForResult() .. this is then observed on livedata in ActivityB for resultCode and perform dismiss of ActivityB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249726/discussion-between-yatin-and-blackapps).

Comment: No no chatting. Please tell what you really need. As changeing in a working app some startActivityForResult's with registerfor does not change the logic of the app and your app should work as it did before. So please tell which problem you really face.

Comment: @blackapps : So real issue is with implementation . 
I use registerForActivityResult in ActivityA  ? 
and how do I get a callback from Fragment for resultCode .. ?

Actually , I wanted to understand what would you have done here .. its bit confusing for me.

Comment: @blackapps : Actually , I need how do I implement a callback from Fragment to Activity. 

So how do I create  MyLifecycleObserver from fragment to Activity communication for ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult

Comment: `changeing in a working app some startActivityForResult's with registerfor does not change the logic of the app and your app should work as it did before. ` Sorry i have no idea which problem you have.

Comment: @blackapps : I am not able to use MyLifecycleObserver to use ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult   

I saw this communication between Fragment and Activity .. like Fragment calls new Activity and then Activity which hosts this Fragment ... needs to pass result to Activity and that hostActivity needs to be finish

Comment: Why are you not able?

Comment: @blackapps : ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult in MyLifecycleObserver class

Comment: My god.. why not!?

Comment: @blackapps : I have posted / edit it in question again .

Comment: I have no idea which problem you have as you still did not tell.